# Reverse to the same page with pk as slug field after submit. Error:Reverse with no arguments not found

Tags: python, django, django-views

following scenario: I do have a edit profile page which pulls the data from db so the user can change them. After submitting everything gets stored in the db but the reverse doesn't seem to work. Basically I don't know how to give the pk along to be able to call the same site with reverse.

views.py

```
class EditUserProfileView(UpdateView):
    model = UserProfileInfo
    form_class = UserProfileForm
    template_name = "accounts/user_profile.html"

    def get_object(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = get_object_or_404(User, pk=self.kwargs['pk'])

        return user.userprofileinfo

    def get_success_url(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if 'pk' in self.kwargs:
            pk = self.kwargs['pk']
        else:
            slug = 'main'

        return reverse("accounts:edit")
```

urls.py

```
app_name = 'accounts'

urlpatterns=[
    url(r'^edit/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.EditUserProfileView.as_view(), name="edit-user-profile"),
]
```

html from where I call the edit-user-profile

```
<li class="nav-item nav-link">Hello <a href="{% url 'accounts:edit-user-profile' pk=user.pk %}">{{user.first_name}}</a></li>
```

Cheers

Comment: Have you tried using `<a href="{% url 'accounts:edit-user-profile' pk=form.instance.pk %}` (or just `<a href="{% url 'accounts:edit-user-profile' form.instance.pk %}`)?

Comment: The referring to edit-user-profile works fine. The error was more around the views.py at " return reverse("accounts:edit") ". But schobwaseggl answered worked out good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both [`reverse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse) and [`reverse_lazy`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse-lazy) have the  keyword arguments `args` and `kwargs`that you can pass a list or dict of view arguments:

```
return reverse("accounts:edit-user-profile", kwargs={'pk': pk})
```